# ip_nonlocal_bind not working

Tags: ubuntu, networking, sysctl

I have 2 servers, same specs, OS (ubuntu 20.04), networks and don't have ndppd installed.
One has `2602:fe90:100:41::/64`, other has `2602:fe90:100:40::/64`

After enabling `net.ipv6.ip_nonlocal_bind=1` on both servers, only server `2602:fe90:100:41::/64` can use IPv6 addresses without binding addresses to network interfaces.
So what's wrong with server `2602:fe90:100:40::/64`?

I tested with command: `curl -6 --interface random_IPv6_from_subnet icanhazip.com`

Comment: @A.B both servers are the same settings... but only one can work with ip_nonlocal_bind, so it's problem I want to ask